# Find and download file(s) using PuTTY

Tags: windows-7, osx-snow-leopard, putty

I'm trying to use PuTTY to connect via SSH to a Mac and download some files specified using a find command. The files have spaces in them that may be causing issues and I'm not sure how to specify a local Windows path.

I'm trying something like this, unsuccessfully so far:

```
find . -iname "*searchtext*" | xargs -0 scp user@host:{} localpath
```

Any ideas?

If it's not possible using one line, I don't mind a Bash script that can be called via PuTTY?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are best off just creating a zip or tgz of the files on the remote server

```
zip found-files.zip $(find . -iname "*searchtext*")
```

And then just use [winscp](http://winscp.net/eng/index.php) to download the found-files.zip file. Winscp will authenticate the same as putty (passwords or uses pagent if running). If you prefer the dos command prompt you can use pscp

Comment: (virtual +1) @Sodved Thanks. I went for the zip solution. Had to change it to deal with spaces issue. @grawity's suggestions helped.


find . -iname "*searchtext*" -print0 | xargs -0 zip found-files.zip

and then

pscp user@host:found-files.zip <localpath>

Answer (score 1):

> I'm trying to use PuTTY to connect via SSH to a Mac and download some files specified using a find command.

Are you trying to download the files to your local Windows system?

Remember that PuTTY is a SSH client. All it does is send typed text to your Mac and display received output. Therefore, when you run `scp` like this, *it runs on the Mac* and the file names must be specified as seen by the Mac.

If you want to transfer files from Mac to Windows, then it's `scp macpath user@windowshost:windowspath`. (You seem to have this reversed in your example command.)

This also means that your Windows computer needs a SSH server installed with SCP capabilities, and that it must allow incoming SSH connections.

---

> I'm not sure how to specify a local Windows path.

It depends on the SSH server that you installed on Windows. (See paragraph above.) But usually, `x:\dir\file` can be converted to `/x/dir/file`. Read the manual.

---

> The files have spaces in them that may be causing issues

Yes, this causes problem with `xargs`. You went to the right direction with `xargs -0`, but you need to do the same with `find` – `find .... -print0` or `find .... -printf "%p\0"`.

If the version of `find` in Mac OS X supports neither `-print0` nor `-printf`, you can get away with using newlines as separators. In this case, do not add any special options to `find`, but change `xargs -0` to `xargs -d '\n'`.

A better alternative to `xargs` is `find -exec`.

---

> `xargs -0 scp user@host:{} localpath`

There is one more mistake here. By default, `xargs` does *not* replace `{}` with the file name; you have to specifically tell it to, using `-I "{}"`.

You might have confused this with the `-exec` option in `find`, which *does* work like this:

```
find . -iname "*searchtext*" -exec scp user@host:{} localpath \;
```

Above, I left `scp` argument order exactly as it was in your original example. But like I said before, it's incorrect.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. Yes I'm trying to download files to the local Windows system. So I guess my approach is wrong. Is there a way for scp (or pscsp.exe in my case) to copy files that are outputted from a find command executed remotely? Or is there any other way to achieve this?

Comment: @Vivek: You could use `psftp.exe` in batch mode: 1) create a file with the results: `find .... -print | sed 's/^/get /' > psftp-batch.txt` 2) copy the file to Windows machine and run `psftp -b psftp-batch.txt -bc user@machost`.

Comment: Cheers. (virtual +1)